# What is the goal of the minSearchTime argument in the PyAutoGUI locateOnScreen method?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I can't see any difference between

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.locateOnScreen("anImage")
```

and

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.locateOnScreen("anImage", minSearchTime=10)
```

And there is no explanation nor reference in documentation about `minSearchTime`.

Comment: Where did you discover the option to supply the argument?

Comment: You can see this argument when you use bpython.

Answer (score 2):

It's useful when you want to wait some time for an image to appear. PyAutoGUI will keep making screenshots and searching for the image until the minSearchTime has passed.
I got this from the source code:

```html
def locateOnScreen(image, minSearchTime=0, **kwargs):
    """minSearchTime - amount of time in seconds to repeat taking
    screenshots and trying to locate a match.  The default of 0 performs
    a single search.
    """
    start = time.time()
    while True:
        try:
            screenshotIm = screenshot(region=None) # the locateAll() function must handle cropping to return accurate coordinates, so don't pass a region here.
            retVal = locate(image, screenshotIm, **kwargs)
            try:
                screenshotIm.fp.close()
            except AttributeError:
                # Screenshots on Windows won't have an fp since they came from
                # ImageGrab, not a file. Screenshots on Linux will have fp set
                # to None since the file has been unlinked
                pass
            if retVal or time.time() - start > minSearchTime:
                return retVal
        except ImageNotFoundException:
            if time.time() - start > minSearchTime:
                raise
```